# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/naming/NameCode error in setting up restful webservice in spring 4.3.1

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I want to create rest controller in spring but I get this error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0'
>   defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/naming/NameCoder

These jar files were added to my project correctly :
jackson-annotations:2.1.1/
jackson-core:2.1.1/
jackson-databind:2.1.2

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.version}</version>
          </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Why would you add Jackson if it complains clearly about XStream. Next to that why ar eyou using that old version of Jackson.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am learning from a video tutorial and he is using it.I was used ${spring.version} first and other jackson artifactid but I read somewhere with same problem that it is old(I think it was 1.3)

Comment: The current version of Jackson is 2.8.1.

Comment: @chrylis I was changed current version. But I have problem yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced same problem in my first spring boot web application, even after adding aforementioned dependency if it does not solve this issue, we could try deleting .m2 local repository, and then do maven build, and maven install.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-xstream</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

to make everyone happy.